# Sorting function by desc, asc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I have Table component with columns array, and data array. I need sort columns and update table state of table. My method receives two arguments *key*(columns key) and *sortable*(true or false columns sortable or not) from columns, what I mess? What is the best solution to sorting table column?  How to make it simple, and sort by number and string

```
const columns = [
    {
        key: 'deviceType',
        label:'Device Type',
        numeric: false,
    }, {
        key: 'deviceID',
        label:'Device ID',
        sortable: true,
        numeric: true,
        // cellRenderer: ({item, key}) =>
        //          <Button >Default</Button>,
    }, {
        key: 'name',
        label: 'Name',
        sortable: false,
        numeric: false,

    },{
        key: 'currentVersion',
        label: 'Current Version',
        sortable: false,
        numeric: false,
    },{
        key: 'location',
        label: 'Location',
        sortable: false,
        numeric: false,
    },{
        key: 'status',
        label: 'Status',
        sortable: false,
        numeric: false,
    },{
        key: 'lastAliveMessage',
        label: 'Last alive message',
        sortable: false,
        numeric: false,
    }, {
        key: 'action',
        label: 'Actions',
        cellRenderer: () => <SimpleMenu />,
    }]

const data = [
    { key: 1, deviceType: 'Tag', deviceID: 1, name:'Tag For sending an ', location: 'Room_104', status: 'assigned'},
    { key: 2, deviceType: 'Tag', deviceID: 2, name:'Tag For sending an ', location: 'Room_104', status: 'assigned'},
    { key: 3, deviceType: 'Tag', deviceID: 3, name:'Tag For sending an ', location: 'Room_104', status: 'assigned'},
    { key: 4, deviceType: 'Tag', deviceID: 4, name:'Tag For sending an ', location: 'Room_104', status: 'assigned'},
    { key: 5, deviceType: 'Tag', deviceID: 5, name:'Tag For sending an ', location: 'Room_104', status: 'assigned'},
]

class EnhancedTable extends Component {
    state = {
        selected: [],
        data,
        order: 'asc',
        search: '',
    }

    handleRequestSort = (key, sortable) => {
        let order = 'desc'

        // if (this.state.order.by === key && this.state.order.direction === 'desc') {
        //     order = 'asc'
        // }
        if (sortable && this.state.order.direction === 'desc') {
            order = 'asc'
        }
        const data = this.state.data.sort(
            (a, b) => {
                order === 'desc' ? b[key] > a[key] : a[key] > b[key]},
        )

        this.setState({ data, order })
    }
```

Comment: maybe worth to mention, [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) expect to get not `true` or `false`, but a value smaller than zero, zero or a value greater than zero.

Answer (score 4):

`sort` does inplace array modification. And you forgot to return.

```
const data = this.state.data.slice()
data.sort(
            (a, b) => {
                return order === 'desc' ? b[key] > a[key] : a[key] > b[key]
            },
        )
```

Or remove `{}`

```
 data.sort(
   (a, b) => (order === 'desc' ? b[key] > a[key] : a[key] > b[key]),
 )
```

Comment: indeed, yes, it works, by it sort only one, second click(trigger) are not update the data

Comment: I found thanks, I've got not a good conditions
should be if (sortable && this.state.order === 'desc') {
            order = 'asc'
        }

Comment: @PalaniichukDmytro  You might switch direction like this. `const order = {asc: 'desc', desc: 'asc'}[this.state.order]`